# sinon-chai not catching promise rejection

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai

//foo.js

```
const api = require('someApi');
exports.get = obj => {
  if (!obj.id) {
     return Promise.reject('no id');
  }

  api.get(obj.id)... 
}
```

//foo.spec.js

```
 let getStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getStub = sinon.stub(api, 'get');
  });

   it('should fail to retrieve location on insufficient data', () => {
    let obj = {};
    foo.get(obj)
      .catch(err => {
        getStub.should.have.not.been.called();
        expect(err).to.not.equal('undefined');
      })

  });
```

When i execute the test I receive this error:

```
(node:73773) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

There is no other stack trace to the error. As far as i can see I have handling the promise rejection by catching the error in the catch block.

Is this a good way to test and how should I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the "it" block finished before the catch block catches the exception.  You can add a 'done' call to prevent this:

```
it('should fail to retrieve location on insufficient data', (done) => 
{
    let obj = {};
    foo.get(obj)
      .catch(err => {
        getStub.should.have.not.been.called();
        expect(err).to.not.equal('undefined');
        done();
      })
}
```